# React/Gatsby component interaction (lifting state up) with components in MDX files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I use Gatsby with the MDX plugin. So I can use React components in markdown. That's fine.

I have components, talking to each other. To do this I use the [Lifting State Up Pattern](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). That's fine.

Here is a basic Counter example, to show my proof of concept code.

```
import React from "react"

export class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { count: 0 }
    this.handleCounterUpdate = this.handleCounterUpdate.bind(this)
  }

  handleCounterUpdate() {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })
  }

  render() {
    const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
      const additionalProps = {}
      additionalProps.count = this.state.count
      additionalProps.handleCounterUpdate = this.handleCounterUpdate
      return React.cloneElement(child, additionalProps)
    })
    return <div>{children}</div>
  }
}

export function Display({ count }) {
  return <h2>Current counter is: {count}</h2>
}

export function UpdateButton({ handleCounterUpdate }) {
  return <button onClick={handleCounterUpdate}>Increment couter by one</button>
}
```

With this setup, one can use the components like this

```
<Counter>
  <Display />
  <UpdateButton />
</Counter>
```

or even like this

```
<Counter>
  <Display />
  <UpdateButton />
  <Display />
  <Display />
</Counter>
```

That's fine.

In real-world, the enclosing Counter component (state holder), will be something like a Layout component. The `<Layout>` is used in a template and renders the MDX pages. This looks like that:

```
<SiteLayout>
  <SEO title={title} description={description} />
  <TopNavigation />
  <Display />       // The state holder is <SiteLayout>, not <Counter> 
  <Breadcrumb location={location} />
  <MDXRenderer>{page.body}</MDXRenderer>  // The rendered MDX
</SiteLayout>
```

The `<UpdateButton>` (in real-world something like `<AddToCartButton>`) is on the MDX page and not anymore a direct child from the `<Layout>` component.

The pattern does not work anymore.

How can I resolve this?

Thanks all

Comment: You should be able to pass the prop from your ```<MDXRenderer />``` down to the ```<AddToCartButton>```

Comment: I think you can set up a context provider & consume its state in the indirect child components

Comment: Thanks @Mark Do you propse extending and overriding `MDXRenderer`?  I'm still learning React.

Comment: Thanks  @DerekNguyen. Will google and read first. Still do not know the concept of context provider in React. Saw also Hooks. Will learn and see, if it helps. Redux and similar are overkill in my case. The app-part is limited. The site I redesign is content centric with a few app features. I'll come back after doing my homework.

Comment: Stefan, I would actually recommend what Derek is proposing.  It will give you a good lesson the context API.

Comment: Yes @Mark. I realized this too. Did the reading and made a POC. Everything woks nice. Will post it as a solution for other beginners like me. If You like, make comment and  suggestion for improvement. Thanks all for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React from "react"

// This is a proof of concept (POC) for intercomponent communication using
// React Context
//
// In the real world Gatsby/React app we use a kind of cart summary component
// at top right of each page. The site consists of thousands of pages with detailed
// product information and a blog. Users have the possibility to add products directly
// from product information pages and blog posts. Posts and pages are written in
// MDX (Mardown + React components). All <AddToCartButtons> reside in MDX files.
//
// This code uses a "increment counter button" (= add to cart button) and a
// display (= cart summary) as POC
//
// More information at
// https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component

export const CounterContext = React.createContext()

// The <Layout> component handles all business logic. Thats fine. We have
// very few app features.
export class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleCounterUpdate = this.handleCounterUpdate.bind(this)
    this.state = { count: 0, increment: this.handleCounterUpdate }
  }

  handleCounterUpdate() {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: "silver", padding: "20px" }}>
        <CounterContext.Provider value={this.state}>
          {this.props.children}
        </CounterContext.Provider>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export class UpdateButton extends React.Component {
  static contextType = CounterContext
  render() {
    const count = this.context.count
    const increment = this.context.increment
    return (
      <button onClick={increment}>
        Increment counter (current value: {count})
      </button>
    )
  }
}

export class Display extends React.Component {
  static contextType = CounterContext

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "white",
          padding: "10px",
          margin: "10px 0 0 0"
        }}
      >
        <div>I'm Display. I know the count: {this.context.count}</div>
        <div>{this.props.children}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// Function components use <CounterContext.Consumer>. Class components
// use static contextType = CounterContext
export function AChild() {
  return (
    <CounterContext.Consumer>
      {context => (
        <span>
          I'm a child of Display. I know the count too: {context.count}
        </span>
      )}
    </CounterContext.Consumer>
  )
}
```

Use it like this

```
<Layout>
  <Display>
    <AChild />
  </Display>
  // UpdateButton inside MDX files
  <MDXRenderer>{page.body}</MDXRenderer>
 // Or elsewhere
  <UpdateButton /> 
</Layout>
```